# How can I get first data while using MouseAdapter?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I want to make code that When I pressed left upper area, the rectangle chosen and resize it using drag and drop (right down is fixed and use left up point to resize).

```
class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        start = e.getPoint();
        if((up.a<start.x&&start.x<up.a+10&&up.b<start.y&&start.y<up.b+10)) {//When I pressed Rectangle's left up area
            Label.setText("up");
            if(tempshape==null) {
                tempshape=shapes.get(now);
            }
            ud=1;
        }
```

`tempshape` is a global variable and I want to get only first data so
I claimed `tempshape` as:

```
shape tempshape=null;
    if(ud==1) {
         else if(nowshape=="Rectangle") {
             shapes.get(now).setA(end.x);
             shapes.get(now).setB(end.y);
             shapes.get(now).setC(tempshape.c+end.x);
             shapes.get(now).setD(tempshape.d+end.y);
         }
    } ]
```

But tempshape is still update it's value while I dragging so I get trash data from `tempshape`.
I want to know:

1. Why `tempshape` is updating while dragging? (I only Write `tempshape`'s update code in pressed.)
2. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't use "==" for Object comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.